# jQuery: Running a random number generator on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a rock, paper, scissors game to learn JS and jQuery with. What I'm trying to figure out is how to call the same function on button click, so that the number will change, giving a different result for the game.

I've made a jsFiddle demo for this here:

https://jsfiddle.net/iKaleb/v1kbxg2g/3/

Essentially, in the fiddle example, I'd like to click the blue box and the computers choice would change every time. `compChoice()` is the random number generator, but when I call it again by clicking the button, it doesn't change the computers choice.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

```
var player = "Rock";
var computer = compChoice();

function compChoice() {
    var compMath = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

    switch (compMath) {
        case 1: 
            pick = "Rock"
            break;
        case 2:
            pick = "Paper"
            break;
        case 3:
            pick = "Scissors"
            break;
    }

    return pick;
}

function vsChoice() {
    if (player === "Rock") {
        if (computer === "Scissors") {
            console.log("Win.");
        } else if (player === computer) {
            console.log("Tie.");
        } else {
            console.log("Lose.");
        }
    }

    if (player === "Paper") {
        if (computer === "Rock") {
            console.log("Win.");
        } else if (player === computer) {
            console.log("Tie.");
        } else {
            console.log("Lose.");
        }
    }

    if (player === "Scissors") {
        if (computer === "Paper") {
            console.log("Win.");
        } else if (player === computer) {
            console.log("Tie.");
        } else {
            console.log("Lose.");
        }
    }
}

$('#box').on('click', function() {
    console.log("Players Choice: " + player);
    console.log("Computer Choice: " + computer);
    vsChoice();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call function that generates the choice instead of showing the same value every time:

```
$('#box').on('click', function() {
    computer = compChoice(); 
    console.log("Players Choice: " + player);
    console.log("Computer Choice: " + computer);
    vsChoice();
});
```

Note that it would be better to pass choice as parameters to `vsChoice` function instead of using global variables.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works! I'll have to take your advice in not using global variables.

Answer (score 2):

I just edited your js and it is working for me

```
function compChoice() {
    compMath = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

    switch (compMath) {
        case 1: 
            pick = "Rock"
            break;
        case 2:
            pick = "Paper"
            break;
        case 3:
            pick = "Scissors"
            break;
    }

    return pick;
}

function compChoice() {
    var compMath = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

    switch (compMath) {
        case 1: 
            pick = "Rock"
            break;
        case 2:
            pick = "Paper"
            break;
        case 3:
            pick = "Scissors"
            break;
    }

    return pick;
}

function vsChoice() {
    if (player === "Rock") {
        if (computer === "Scissors") {
            console.log("Win.");
        } else if (player === computer) {
            console.log("Tie.");
        } else {
            console.log("Lose.");
        }
    }

    if (player === "Paper") {
        if (computer === "Rock") {
            console.log("Win.");
        } else if (player === computer) {
            console.log("Tie.");
        } else {
            console.log("Lose.");
        }
    }

    if (player === "Scissors") {
        if (computer === "Paper") {
            console.log("Win.");
        } else if (player === computer) {
            console.log("Tie.");
        } else {
            console.log("Lose.");
        }
    }
}

$('#box').on('click', function() {
    player = compChoice();
    computer = compChoice();
    console.log("Players Choice: " + player);
    console.log("Computer Choice: " + computer);
    vsChoice();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Your Mistake is

You are printing initial computed value.

Try like this

```
$('#box').on('click', function() {   
    console.log("Players Choice: " + player);
    console.log("Computer Choice: " + compChoice());
    vsChoice();
});
```

OR

Refreshing your computed value computer var

```
function compChoice() {
    var compMath = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    debugger;
    switch (compMath) {
        case 1: 
            pick = "Rock"
            break;
        case 2:
            pick = "Paper"
            break;
        case 3:
            pick = "Scissors"
            break;
    }

computer = pick;
    return pick;
}
```

## JSFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/v1kbxg2g/7/